# Blazor Authentication not working in Live but working in devolopment

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

Using asp.net core default authentication that's working well in local machine in live publish and places in azure that's not working, error occured.

asp.net core: 3.0 used

Error screenshot
[image: **enter image description here**]

appsetting.json

```
{

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "SERVER=servername;INITIAL CATALOG=catlogname;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=FALSE;USER ID=dbname;PASSWORD=****;MULTIPLEACTIVERESULTSETS=FALSE;ENCRYPT=TRUE;TRUSTSERVERCERTIFICATE=FALSE;CONNECTION TIMEOUT=30;"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"

    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62632",
      "sslPort": 44336
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "LabOrg": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using?

Comment: .net core default authentication

Comment: There is no authentication by default in Core. You have to configure some scheme. Is it OpenID Connect? Integrated Windows auth? Cookie auth? Bearer token auth?

Comment: Individual User Accounts – User accounts can be stored:
Within the app using ASP.NET Core's Identity system.

Comment: Okay, so then there might be database connection problems etc. You should check the logs for your app to see what the issue is. If you run on Azure App Service, there is a Diagnostic Logs configuration where you can see logs in real time.

Comment: Okay, thanks i check on the same